# Instantiate a bullet towards player position

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

On input left click (Fire1), the projectile spawns from the projectileSpawn position. On right click(Fire2), I want to have the projectile shoot "in reverse" and start from the projectileSpawnTwo position and back to the initial projectileSpawn location. It currently shoots forward but I want the projectile to spawn back to an exact position.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlayerWeapon : MonoBehaviour 
{
    public GameObject projectilePrefab;

    public GameObject projectileTwoPrefab;

    public Transform projectileSpawn;
    public Transform projectileSpawnTwo;

    public float projectileSpeed = 30;  

    void Update () 
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
        {
            Fire();
        }

        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")) 
        {
            Fire2();
        }
    }

    private void Fire() 
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab);

        Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(),
                                projectileSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>()); 

        projectile.transform.position = projectileSpawn.position;

        var rot = projectile.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

        projectile.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rot.z);

        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(projectileSpawn.forward * projectileSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);       
    }

    private void Fire2()
    {
        GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectileTwoPrefab);

        Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(),
                                projectileSpawnTwo.parent.GetComponent<Collider>()); 

        projectile.transform.position = projectileSpawnTwo.position;

        var rot = projectile.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

        projectile.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rot.z);

        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(projectileSpawnTwo.forward * projectileSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Since both methods are very similar to generalize your method a bit you could do

```
private Collider projectileSpawnParentCollider;

privtae enum FireType
{
    One,
    Two
}

private void Awake()
{
  // this hould probably done only once to be more efficient
  projectileSpawnParentCollider = projectileSpawn.parent.GetComponent<Collider>();
}

private void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) 
    {
        Fire(FireType.One);
    }

    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire2")) 
    {
        Fire(FireType.Two);
    }
}

private void Fire(FireType fireType) 
{
    var position = fireType == FireType.One ? projectileSpawn.position : projectileSpawnTwo.position;

    var rot = projectile.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rot.z);

    // pass the position and rotation alraedy
    GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, position, rotation);

    Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(), projectileSpawnParentCollider);


    var forceDirection = fireType == FireType.One ? projectileSpawn.forward : (projectileSpawn.position - projectileSpawnTwo.position).normalized;

    projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(forceDirection * projectileSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
}
```

The

```
projectileSpawn.position - projectileSpawnTwo.position
```

returns a Vector pointing from `projectileSpawnTwo.position` towards `projectileSpawn.position`. Using `normalized` returns a vector with the same direction but with `magnitude = 1`.

---

However, note that this only works ofcourse if the player is not moving after the second shoot. If the player can move you should probably rather implement another component for making the bullet object actually follow the player position.

You could use [`Quaternion.LookRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Quaternion.LookRotation.html) and [`Rigidbody.MoveRotation`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MoveRotation.html) to write a separate component like e.g.

```
public class FollowPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Transform PlayerTransform;
    public RigidBody rigiBody;
    public speed;

    private void Awake()
    {
       rigidBody = GetComponent<RigidBody>();
    }

    private void LateUpdate()
    {
        if(!PlayerTrasnform) return;

        var rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(PlayerTransform.position - transform.position, Vector3.up);

        rigidBody.MoveRotation(rotation);
        rigidBody.velocity = (PlayerTransform.position - transform.position).normalized * speed;
    }
}
```

and in your script add the component in case two like

```
private void Fire(FireType fireType) 
{
    var position = fireType == FireType.One ? projectileSpawn.position : projectileSpawnTwo.position;

    var rot = projectile.transform.rotation.eulerAngles;

    var rotation = Quaternion.Euler(rot.x, transform.eulerAngles.y, rot.z);

    // pass the position and rotation alraedy
    GameObject projectile = Instantiate(projectilePrefab, position, rotation);

    Physics.IgnoreCollision(projectile.GetComponent<Collider>(), projectileSpawnParentCollider);

    if(fireType == FireType.One)
    {
        projectile.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(projectileSpawn.forward * projectileSpeed, ForceMode.Impulse);
    }
    else
    {
        var follow = projectile.AddComponent<FollowPlayer>();
        follow.speed = projectileSpeed;
        follow.PlayerTransform = YourPlayerTransform; // or probably projectileSpawn
    }
}
```

---

*Note: Typed on smartphone so no warrenty but I hope the idea gets clear.*

Comment: Huge thanks! Follow the player would actually be preferable. Would you know the simplest way to implement this with the current code? I feel that is such simple solution but can't seem to make  the code work

Comment: @CharlotteBarnekow see my Update. I didn't test it but something like that should do it hopefully. The thing is that dealing with RigidBody here makes it slightly more difficult ;)

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to help! I Implemented your code with  mine and it works now